# How to search a string with parentheses using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, parentheses

I have a txt file containing strings as:

```
   A 123
   B  456
   Ab(123)
   ......
```

I wish to search `Ab(123)` in txt file.

What I have tried :

```
re.search(r'Ab(123)',string)
```

Comment: Parantheses in regular expressions are reserved for capture groups and thus need to be escaped with backslashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 12 characters with special meanings, you escape to its literal meaning with `\` in front of it.

```
re.search(r'Ab\(123\)',string)

# or re.findall(r'Ab\(123\)',string)
```

Look up https://regex101.com/r/1bb8oz/1 for detail.

Answer (score 2):

## `Ab\(123\)`

In regex, there are 12 characters with special meanings: the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, the dollar sign `$`, the period or dot `.`, the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`, the question mark `?`, the asterisk or star `*`, the plus sign `+`, the opening parenthesis `(`, the closing parenthesis `)`, the opening square bracket `[`, and the opening curly brace `{`, these special characters are often called  [`metacharacters`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003288497.htm) and should be escaped with backslash `Ab\(123\)` if used as literal.
 This  can be *automagically*  achieved using [re.escape()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.escape)

```
import re
string = "some text Ab(123) and more text"
if re.search(re.escape("Ab(123)"),string):
  print("match")
```

---

- [Regex Special Characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)
- [Python Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/b11f773d3a)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need regex in the first place, if your goal is just to extract the lines where you have parentheses.

You could use the following approach:

**input:**

```
$ cat parentheses.txt 
A 123
B  456
Ab(123)
uV(a5afgsg3)
A 123
```

**output:**

```
$ python parentheses.py 
['Ab(123)', 'uV(a5afgsg3)']
```

**code:**

```
with open('parentheses.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content if '(' in x and ')' in x]
print(content)
```

If you really want to use regex:

```
import re

s = """
A 123
B  456
Ab(123)
uV(a5afgsg3)
A 123
"""
print(re.findall(r'^.*?\(.*?\).*$',s,re.MULTILINE))
```

**output:**

```
['Ab(123)', 'uV(a5afgsg3)']
```

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/PGsguA/1